# When does the "caching module" request authorization?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.oncacheauthorization%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for `OnCacheAuthorization` says

> Called when the caching module requests authorization.

When is that?  When something is retrieved from the cache?  When it is added to the cache?  Why don't we have a `AuthorizationContext` for it like we do with a normal authorization?